# DataTable showing wrong Sorting for Number Column

Tags: datatable, columnsorting

I am using DataTables, but I am getting wrong sorting by number column.
it is showing like this.

[image: This is how it is showing]

It should show `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ....`

How I can achieve this. Here is what I tried.

```
$('#RecTable').DataTable({
      //"aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc"]], /*row count starts from 0 in datatables*/
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [1] }]

     });
```

Can anyone help me on this please.

Comment: A guess, the numbers are stored as strings.

Comment: Just to check: Is this really the second column in your table (`"aTargets": [1]`), or is it the first column: `"aTargets": [0]`? Columns are zero-indexed.

Comment: Also, this is not required, but... Unless you are using a very old version of DataTables, I think it is worth updating your parameter names to use the [modern naming standards](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert). So, for example, `aoColumnDefs` becomes `columnDefs`, `aTargets` becomes `targets`, and so on.

Comment: @andrewjames It is the First Column in my Table

Comment: One more thing to check: Try `num` instead of `numeric` for the type. See [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type).

Comment: @andrewjames Tried This `"ColumnDefs": [{ "sType": "numeric", "Targets": [0]}]` Still Failed

Comment: @andrewjames With num still issue
`"ColumnDefs": [{ "sType": "num", "Targets": [0]}]`

Comment: Understood - then you need to show us your data - enough so that we can create a [mre]. As you can see, without that, it's just guesswork.

Comment: It is about 108 Records. let me share a Link of JS fiddle with you

Comment: Note the "minimal" in MRE. You don't have to show _all_ your data - just enough to recreate the problem in a reliable way.

Comment: @andrewjames Here is fiddle Link. having my table's some records. 
https://jsfiddle.net/baberzaman/q8ozLts7/

Comment: That's not a MRE. There is no DataTables code in that fiddle.

Comment: @andrewjames It is strange. When I placed My All Code in the JSFiddle. it shown Correct Sorting. But In my Web Code. it is showing wrong

Comment: Until you can create a [mre], we cannot help you. Bear in mind that even one non-numeric value in your table data will cause every value to be treated as text. So, look for something which is not a number in that column of data which is supposed to be numeric.

Comment: Yes You are Right. I just removed one 72A and Now all remaining are Pure Numeric Values. And it is Sorted Out. But is there anyway to Sort with Alpha Numeric Values?

Comment: I sorted it out even with 72A. I have used trick to just get only Numerics from this Column and Added a Serial Number Column as Column 0 So it converted 72A to 72 and Managed to proper Place

Comment: Great - glad you solved it!